# JQuery: What is the matching selector if the structure same?

Tags: jquery

In my [example](http://jsfiddle.net/somaberlin/3rk1sz2L/4/) there are two lists with the same structure. Here the structure of one element.

```
<div class="box">
  <button class="next">Next</button>
  <ul class="myList">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li class="current">3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

So when I click on the button inside the DIV (.box) than change something in this box only. I don't want to change class name or use id, if possible.

Comment: The trick is to use the `$(this)` object.

Comment: i don't think the OP is clicking the `<li>`; they're clicking the button and expecting the `.current` class to move on one step

Answer (score 2):

Use [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find the required parent, like:

```
$('.next').on("click", function(){
    var parent = $(this).closest('.box');
    //other stuff
});
```

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/3rk1sz2L/6/)

Comment: Note that `$.parent()` slightly outperforms `$.closest()`.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways of doing this. You can't use the global class selector, as you want to restrict the selection within a certain part of the DOM. Check out [jQuery's hierarchial selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/hierarchy-selectors/).

One way of doing this is by traversing to the parent, and finding the matched elements within that.

```
var current = $(this).parent().find('li.current');
current.removeClass('current').next('li').addClass('current');
```

[Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/3rk1sz2L/7/)